# Multiple frames and child frames not showing up and placed correctly in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, resize, parent-child

I'm trying to learn both python and tkinter by creating a very simple musical scores-writing software. At the moment, I have many issues.

I'm using many frames, each one with its own canvas inside.
There is the `class MainFrame(tk.Frame)`, which is supposed to be invisible and to extend for the entire tkinter window. On it are attached the scrollbars.
Inside the `MainFrame()` there is another invisible frame called `sub_Mainframe` equally large, in which I created a grid where to `.grid` all the subsequent elements.
Then, there is the `class Page()`, which is again a frame and a canvas.
In it there is the `class Margins()` frame, that is supposed to lay inside the page and to be smaller than its parent, according to the variables (`left_margin`, `right_margin`, `top_margin`, `bottom_margin`) that I declared at the beginning of the code, and that for visualisation purposes I coloured in blue.
Then, there is the `class Staff()` class, again basically made of a margin and a canvas, that is supposed to be high as a custom variable that I would later assign to user input, and as large as the margin frame.

Here the entire code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

#Colors
app_background_color='#1a4120'
widget_colors='#2a381f'
white='white'
black='black'
page_color=white
transarent_color='yellow'

number_of_instruments = 2

page_width = 700
page_height = 700

top_margin = 0
bottom_margin = 0
left_margin = 0
right_margin = 0

staff_columns_grid_parameter = 100

#Software Window

class ScorePad(tk.Tk): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #Main Window Setup
        self.title('Score Pad')
        self.geometry('600x400')
        app_height = self.winfo_height()
        app_width = self.winfo_width()

        self.minsize(300, 200)
        icon = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\giuli\Coding projects\pyhton score engraver\ScorePadIcon.png")

        self.iconphoto(False, icon)
        
        self['bg']=app_background_color
        self.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', transarent_color)

#MENU BAR SECTION
        menubar = tk.Menu(self, background=widget_colors)
        menubar.configure(bg=widget_colors, fg=white)

        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, background=widget_colors, foreground=white) 
        filemenu.add_command(label="New")

        #open_submenu
        open_submenu = tk.Menu(filemenu, tearoff=0)

        #recentfiles_sub_submenu
        recent_files_sub_submenu = tk.Menu(open_submenu, tearoff=0)

        open_submenu.add_command(label='Browse...', background=widget_colors, foreground=white)

        #add recentfiles_sub_submenu to open_submenu
        open_submenu.add_cascade(label= 'Recent files...', menu=recent_files_sub_submenu, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)

        #add the File menu to the menubar
        filemenu.add_cascade(label="Open", menu=open_submenu, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save")
        filemenu.add_command(label='Save as...')
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)

        editmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)
        editmenu.add_command(label="Undo")
        editmenu.add_command(label="Redo")
        editmenu.add_separator()
        editmenu.add_command(label="Cut")
        editmenu.add_command(label="Copy")
        editmenu.add_command(label="Paste")
        #preferences_submenu
        preferences_submenu = tk.Menu(editmenu, tearoff=0, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)
        preferences_submenu.add_command(label='Customize shortcuts')
        preferences_submenu.add_command(label='Color themes')
        # add the File menu to the menubar
        editmenu.add_cascade(label="Preferences", menu=preferences_submenu, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)

        insertmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)
        insertmenu.add_command(label='Image...') #add image
        insertmenu.add_command(label='Text box') #add a text box - attached to the staff's grid OR to the system itself
        insertmenu.add_command(label='Symbol') #add any symbol possible
        insertmenu.add_command(label='Comment') #add a comment. It might be visible, invisible, typed or handwritten
        insertmenu.add_command(label='Shape') #add shapes of any kind - attached to the staff's grid
        insertmenu.add_command(label='Draw') #hand draw - attached to the stave grid
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Insert', menu=insertmenu, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)

        scoremenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)
        scoremenu.add_command(label='Score format...')
        scoremenu.add_separator()
        scoremenu.add_command(label='Customize style...') #choose fonts, colors, shapes, everything
        scoremenu.add_separator()
        scoremenu.add_command(label='Manage parts...')
        scoremenu.add_command(label='Choose instruments...') #choose which and how many instruments to have
        scoremenu.add_separator()
        scoremenu.add_command(label='Customize staves...') #choose either to have standard or custom staves. You can customise everthing of the stave.
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Score', menu=scoremenu, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)

        pagemenu= tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)
        pagemenu.add_command(label='New page')
        pagemenu.add_command(label='Manage pages...')

        #navigatepages_submenu
        navigatepages_submenu = tk.Menu(pagemenu, tearoff=0, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)
        navigatepages_submenu.add_command(label='First page')
        navigatepages_submenu.add_separator()
        navigatepages_submenu.add_command(label='Previous page')
        navigatepages_submenu.add_command(label='Next page')
        navigatepages_submenu.add_separator()
        navigatepages_submenu.add_command(label='Last page')
        navigatepages_submenu.add_separator()
        navigatepages_submenu.add_command(label='Go to comments...')

        #add the navigatepages_submenu to the page menu 
        pagemenu.add_cascade(label='Navigate pages', menu=navigatepages_submenu, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)
        #add page menu to menu bar
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Page', menu=pagemenu, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)

    
        helpmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index")
        helpmenu.add_command(label="About...")
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu, background=widget_colors, foreground=white)

        self.config(menu=menubar)

        #buttons style
        button_style = ttk.Style()
        button_style.configure('TButton', foreground='white', background=widget_colors, width=4, font='Consolas 10 normal')

        #put mainframe
        MainFrame(self)

        #run
        self.mainloop() 

#create mainframe
class MainFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, background=transarent_color)

        #create MainCanvas
        main_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, background=app_background_color)
        main_canvas.place(x=0, y=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1)

        #place main frame
        self.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        # create right scrollbar
        right_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', highlightcolor=widget_colors, jump=True)
        right_scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

        # create bottom scrollbar
        bottom_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', highlightcolor=widget_colors, jump=True)
        bottom_scrollbar.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')

        right_scrollbar.config(command=main_canvas.yview)  # Change xview to yview
        bottom_scrollbar.config(command=main_canvas.xview)


        main_canvas.config(yscrollcommand=right_scrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=bottom_scrollbar.set)

        #create sub-mainframe with a grid, because otherwise it would contrast with the pack method
        sub_MainFrame=tk.Frame(self, background=app_background_color)
        sub_MainFrame.pack(anchor='center', expand=True, fill='both')

        #create a grid in sub_Mainframe
        
        sub_MainFrame_columns=[*range(10)]
        sub_MainFrame_rows=[*range(100)]
        sub_MainFrame.columnconfigure(index=sub_MainFrame_columns, weight=1)
        sub_MainFrame.rowconfigure(index=sub_MainFrame_rows, weight=1)

        def create_pages(number_of_pages):
            for i in range(number_of_pages):
                if i % 2 == 0:
                    Page(sub_MainFrame, page_index=i)
                # Aggiungi queste linee per mantenere le scrollbar sempre in primo piano
                    
        create_pages(1)

        # Add sub_MainFrame to main_canvas
        main_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=sub_MainFrame, anchor='nw')

        # Update scrollregion after creating pages
        self.update_idletasks()
        main_canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, page_width*2, page_height*2))

#create page
class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, page_index):
        super().__init__(parent, background=page_color, height=page_height, width=page_width)

        #create page canvas
        page_canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        page_canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0, width=page_height, height=page_height)
        page_canvas.pack_propagate(False)
        
        #place page
        self.grid()
        self.grid_propagate(False)

        Margins(self)

#create margin frame
class Margins(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, height=page_height-top_margin-bottom_margin, width=page_width-left_margin-right_margin, borderwidth=0)

        #page grid definition
        margins_frame_columns=[*range(100)]
        margins_frame_rows=[*range(int((page_height-top_margin-bottom_margin)/(page_width-left_margin-right_margin)*100))]

        #create margins canvas
        margins_canvas=tk.Canvas(self, background='blue')
        margins_canvas.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
        margins_canvas.pack_propagate(False)

        margins_canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, page_width, page_height)

        #place margins grid
        margins_canvas.columnconfigure(margins_frame_columns, weight=1)
        margins_canvas.rowconfigure(margins_frame_rows, weight=1)

        margins_canvas.create_window((0,0), anchor='nw', window=self)
        
        #place margins
        self.pack()
        self.pack_propagate(False)

        def Staves(number_of_staves, staff_specific_height, empty_space_specific_height):
            for i in range(number_of_staves*2):
                if (i % 2) == 0:
                    Staff(margins_canvas, number_of_lines=5, staff_height=staff_specific_height, row_index=i+top_margin)
                if (i % 2)-1 == 0:
                    EmptySpace(margins_canvas, empty_space_height=empty_space_specific_height, row_index=i+top_margin)
        
        Staves(number_of_staves=2, staff_specific_height=50, empty_space_specific_height=10)

class EmptySpace(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, empty_space_height, row_index):
        super().__init__(parent, background=page_color, height=empty_space_height, width=page_width-left_margin-right_margin)
        #put a rectangle widget inside to secure the size
        self.create_rectangle(0,0,page_width-left_margin-right_margin,empty_space_height, fill=page_color)
        
        #grid the empty space
        self.grid(column=staff_columns_grid_parameter, row=row_index)


class Staff(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, number_of_lines, staff_height, row_index): #, custom_color_lines, , left_distance
        super().__init__(parent, background=page_color, height=staff_height, width=page_width-left_margin-right_margin, borderwidth=0)

        #staff grid definition
        staff_frame_columns=[*range(1000)]
        staff_frame_rows=[*range(number_of_lines*4)]

        #place staff grid
        self.columnconfigure(staff_frame_columns, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(staff_frame_rows, weight=1)

        #create staff canvas
        staff_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, background='red')
        staff_canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        #place staff
        self.grid(column=staff_columns_grid_parameter, row=row_index, sticky='nswe')
        self.grid_propagate(False)

ScorePad()
```

My issues are:

1. The `class Margins()` is visible when called, but so I want to be its parent `class Page()` surrounding it. But at the moment it doesn't show up.
2. The `Page()` should create a frame detached from the left margin of the tkinter window, but at the moment it is attached to it.
3. If I don't resize the tkinter window by hand with the cursor, the scrollbars get covered by all the elements, whereas I want them to be of course always on the top layer of the window, to be reachable.

Can you help me?

Comment: Parent of `sub_MainFrame` should be `main_canvas` instead of `self`.

Comment: Thank you, now scrollbars are fixed. I still have issues with ```Page()```. Only ```Margins()``` seems to show up, but its parent ```Page()``` should be visible as well behind, larger than ```Margins()```  in all directions depending on the margins variables declared in the beginning. Also, ```Page()``` should be detached from both the left and the top borders of the window, but now it is still attached to them.